# Are the Spelunky Daily Challenges different on each platform?

Tags: spelunky

I have Spelunky on PS4 and my friend got in on Steam. Yesterday we both played the daily challenge but felt we had different seeds. Are they the same on PS4 and Steam? Or are they different?

If they are different, any idea on why that is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While the levels still generate unpredictably, the generation Seed will be constant across all player's sessions, so that the 'daily cave' will be exactly the same for every player in the world.

The game has the PS4 version and the Steam version of the challenge mode. They generate different random seeds on each platform.

[Source 1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fapp%2F239350%2Fdiscussions%2F0%2F558746088923634051%2F&ei=fWFWVNrJCa3xigK464CAAQ&usg=AFQjCNH7IBcxjeS24bGUAIs5eLRc2prHYw&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cGE)

Comment: You're correct, all the levels in Spelunky are randomly generated. But the special thing about the daily challenge is: The level layout is the same (randomly generated) layout for everyone on that day and everyone has one try to beat it. So me and my ps4 owning friends play the same level, but my cool pc playing friend gets another. Why is that and is there a way to change it?

Comment: @user91275 Edited, properly. Sorry for misunderstanding the question.